# Set permission for user to access file via php

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I use Apache on Ubuntu, I want to set permission for two users a and b so that files of b (b is owner) can only access its files (cannot access files of a).

Example: when run b.php which the code bellow, it will throw an error (because a.php owner is a - not b):

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('a.php');?>
```

Hi, I hope you would understand me, my English is not so good...

Thank you for helping.

Comment: @code-jaff it will better than if "a" can access "b" file :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow running file a.php to user "a" only, you should set file rights to that file to owner user "a" and chmod mode set to 600, so no one else will be able to open the file:

```
chown a a.php
chmod 600 a.php
```

Then if user "b" try to run the file a.php using `php -f a.php`, he won't be able to do that and get error message:

```
Could not open input file: a.php
```

If the user "b" try to run file b.php in which is code `file_get_contents('a.php');` script can't open the file and user get this warning:

```
file_get_contents(a.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```